# Cache of my website is not updating. It keeps showing older version

Tags: php, html, css

I recently uploaded my website on a hosting site. I tried to access it from phone and it worked fine. Then, I made few changes to the CSS and HTML pages, and re-uploaded them. I could see the changes take place in my PC browser, but even after multiple refreshing, the site on my Smartphone won't update. It kept showing the previous version. I tried to access it using different browser on the phone, it worked fine.

How can I fix this, and how can I prevent my browser from caching my site the way it did. I do not want to disable caching completely.

P.S: My browser works fine.

Comment: Clear the cache of the browser.

Comment: I know it will help. I understand. But isn't the browser supposed to do it on it's own. Other websites from many sources update fine, but other websites I coded also have this problem.

Comment: Yeah it should but I have also faced this issue many times. Sometimes even clearing the cache don't help.

Comment: Please read https://css-tricks.com/strategies-for-cache-busting-css/